# Grammatical corrections (use of is and has)

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, have

The traditional power grid is designed 120 years ago and has not kept pace with modern-day challenges like....etc

My question is in the first part I used "is" and lateral I used "has not". Is this grammatically okay?  Similary If I use "can not" instead of "has not". Whats the error.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Should be "... _was_  designed 120 years ago"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The traditional power grid WAS designed 120 years ago" is the correct way to say that because it was created in the past. Also "Has not" is correct. Using "can not" wouldnt be correct and you would need to restructure the sentence.

Comment: *has not* and *can not* are both grammatically correct, although they mean slightly different things.

Comment: @PeterShor Surely you can't think that *can not kept pace* is grammatical.